# Transfer Large Files using nio socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to programming. I want to make a program to transfer large file over network using java. May someone please address me of how to write such a program which can efficiently transfer any size of file over network. One person told me to use socket channel and a socket channel for the file but as i am a beginner i can't write the 'Quality Code'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give it a try, write some code, then if you run into some issues, get back to us.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need NIO for this. The standard way to copy between streams in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
 {
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

This works with any buffer size greater than zero. I usually use 8192 bytes or more. Note that you can't do this correctly without storing the read() result into a variable, contrary to what you may read elsewhere.

You will need to add code to create and accept Sockets and get their input and output streams, and to open file input and output streams, and close everything when done,